# "draggable is not a function" when inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to activate the jQuery-ui .draggable-function when the user clicks a button. The scripts are included and OK, because everything is working when I use the following code:

```
<script>
function test() {
$( ".bord" ).draggable({ containment: ".rom", scroll: false });
}
test()
</script>
```

Then the .bord-class is draggable. But I want it to be draggable only when you click a button, so I'm using this code:

```
<script>
function test() {
$( ".bord" ).draggable({ containment: ".rom", scroll: false });
}
$("#bordplassering").click(function() {
    test();
});
</script>
```

And here the problem starts... this gives me the following error:

**"TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function"**

Why!?

Comment: did you add jquery ui in your html ?

Comment: Just looks like something somewhere else in your code removes it from jQuery. Maybe you are includig jQuery more than once, and the last one after including jQuery UI. Or maybe just `$` is no more referring to jQuery

Comment: Actually this was the problem - thank you! jQuery got loaded a second time in the footer.php-file, together with some foundation-files. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Please use it like this: ( You have to move your click function inside document.ready function)

```
<script>
function test() {
$( ".bord" ).draggable({ containment: ".rom", scroll: false });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#bordplassering").click(function() {
        test();
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this structure:

```
 <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".bord").draggable({containment: ".rom", scroll: false});
      });
  </script>
```

But before you will start:

1. jQuery library has to be present at before the call `$`
2. jQuery UI library has to be present at before the call `$()` `$.draggable`

Also you should to read about [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and [DOM ready event](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to apply the draggble function at the start only and on the click you can use enable and disable methods to make it unable and disable.

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-disable

use document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".bord" ).draggable({ containment: ".rom", scroll: false });
    $( ".bord" ).draggable( "disable" );
    $("#bordplassering").click(function() {
       $(".bord").draggable( "enable" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, everyone. As pointed out in a comment up here the problem was that jQuery was loaded a second time in the footer.php-file.

But sure many great ideas to improve the code aswell.